# Definir a primeira letra da $variavel em maiúscula

Tags: php, mysql

Estou utilizando o MYSQL para mostrar alguns dados no meu site... Porém alguns dados ficam em letras minúsculas, e eu preciso que a primeira letra fique em Maiúscula.

Porém não sei como fazer isto utilizando variável... Preciso que os dados da minha variável `"$name"` fique com a primeira letra em maiúscula.

Comment: Links úteis http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.ucfirst.php http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.strtolower.php http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.strtoupper.php

Answer (score 3):

Pode usar o método **[ucfirst](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.ucfirst.php)**, que converte a primeira letra para maiúscula:

```
<?php
$name= "texto";
$name = ucfirst($name);
echo $name; // retorna 'Texto'
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

Caso queira fazer com que todas as palavras da frase fiquem com a primeira letra maiúscula, você também pode usar o ucwords:

```
echo ucwords("olá mundo!");
//Sairá: Olá Mundo!
```

Comment: ucwords tb é legal. +1